# If statements inside JSX with React

Tags: javascript, react-router, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to create a list in React from an array. I have done it with

```
const persons = [
  { name: 'A', website: 'http://google.com' },
  { name: 'B', email: 'b@google.com' },
];

const listItems = persons.map((person, i) =>
  <div className="card" key={i}>
    <div className="card-block">
      <h4 className="card-title">{person.name}</h4>
    </div>
    <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
      <a href="{person.website}" className="list-group-item">{person.website}</a>
      <a href="mailto:{person.email}" className="list-group-item">{person.email}</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
);

const PersonList = () => (
  <div className="card-deck-wrapper">
    {listItems}
  </div>
);
```

The problem is that the data vary, so some persons don't have an email, others don't have a website and some don't have either.

So if a person doesn't have either, this block

```
    <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
      <a href="{person.website}" className="list-group-item">{person.website}</a>
      <a href="mailto:{person.email}" className="list-group-item">{person.email}</a>
    </ul>
```

should be completely omitted.

and if the person doesn't have an email, the email link should be omitted, and if he/she doesn't have a website, this link should be omitted.

So I need some if statements inside my JSX.

What I want is something like this

```
const listItems = persons.map((person, i) =>
  <div className="card" key={i}>
    <div className="card-block">
      <h4 className="card-title">{person.name}</h4>
    </div>
    if (person.website || person.email) {
      <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
        if (person.website) {
          <a href="{person.website}" className="list-group-item">{person.website}</a>
        }
        if (person.email) {
          <a href="mailto:{person.email}" className="list-group-item">{person.email}</a>
        }
      </ul>
    }
  </div>
);
```

but it is not valid JSX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use curly brackets + `&&`  to achieve that.

```
const listItems = persons.map((person, i) =>
  <div className="card" key={i}>
    <div className="card-block">
      <h4 className="card-title">{person.name}</h4>
    </div>
     {(person.website || person.email) &&
         <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
           {person.website && <a href={person.website} className="list-group-item">{person.website}</a>}
           {person.email && <a href={"mailto:" + person.email} className="list-group-item">{person.email}</a>}
        </ul>
    }
  </div>
);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/62798/)

```js
const persons = [
  { name: 'A', website: 'http://google.com' },
  { name: 'B', email: 'b@google.com' },
  { name: "No Email No Website"}
];

const listItems = persons.map((person, i) =>
  <div className="card" key={i}>
    <div className="card-block">
      <h4 className="card-title">{person.name}</h4>
    </div>
     {(person.website || person.email) &&
         <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
           {person.website && <a href={person.website} className="list-group-item">{person.website}</a>}
           {person.email && <a href={"mailto:" + person.email} className="list-group-item">{person.email}</a>}
       </ul>
    }
  </div>
);

const PersonList = () => (
  <div className="card-deck-wrapper">
    {listItems}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <PersonList />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator and conditional operators(&&, ||, ===, !=) to achieve the same

```
{ 
  (person.website || person.email) ? some View when condition is true
   : 
   some View when condition is false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use if statement is JSX block, use ternary operator instead:

```
const listItems = persons.map((person, i) =>
  <div className="card" key={i}>
    <div className="card-block">
      <h4 className="card-title">{person.name}</h4>
    </div>
    {person.website || person.email ? (
      <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
        {person.website ? <a href={person.website} className="list-group-item">{person.website}</a> : null}
        {person.email ? <a href={person.email} className="list-group-item">{person.email}</a> : null}
      </ul>
    ) : null}
  </div>
);
```